# What would be the best way to automate and apply a bucket policy on multiple s3 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Suppose I have more than hundred s3 buckets and I want to apply a bucket policy on all of them so what would be the procedure to automate this?

Comment: Have you looked at awscli?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a script to call an AWS CLI command on each bucket.

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket MyBucket --policy file://policy.json

policy.json:
{
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Deny",
         "Principal": "*",
         "Action": "s3:GetObject",
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/MySecretFolder/*"
      },
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:root"
         },
         "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would call that command in a script or batch file,  once for each bucket.

```
aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket MyBucket0 --policy file://policy.json

aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket MyBucket1 --policy file://policy.json

aws s3api put-bucket-policy --bucket MyBucket2 --policy file://policy.json
```

You should export your list of buckets to a file,  and build the script from that file.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-policy.html

Comment: I like your approach, another approach would be using a boto3 python script to apply bucket policy.

Comment: Sure. Both ways work. For one time tasks like this a simple script  is all you need.